# Git - Update Master branch of fork and then update its feature branch

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control, merge

I forked a repository and created a new branch. After adding new functionality in that branch, i created a pull request and the owner of original repo merged my branch with his master branch. I never updated my master branch.

He then continued to work on his original master branch, where as i continued to work on my forked feature branch.

Now i want to pull the new changes from his original master branch to my forked master branch, and then update my feature branch with it.

How to do this?

Comment: Pull would work. Another option is to rebase your branch on top of his.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

1. Add the original repo as a remote
2. Checkout master, and pull master from that origin
3. Checkout your topic branch
4. Rebase your topic branch onto the updated master branch

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want to pull the new changes from his original master branch to my forked master branch, and then update my feature branch with it.

Its pretty simple to do it:

#### Connect to the second repo (his repo)

Here we have few options:

1. You cloned the project using the original url (his) so you already have it as the default origin. In this case you simply need to fetch the repo and merge the branches.

   ```
   # update your local repo with the remote data
   git fetch --all --prune

   # Checkout the desired branch
   git checkout <branch>

   # grab the content of the remote branch
   git pull origin/master
   ```
2. You did a `fork` and the url is set to your `<account/repo>`. In this case you have to add the remote using:

   ```
   # add the second remote 
   git remote add <name2> <url2>

   # repeat the previous step but use the <name2> instead of origin
   ```

Now you have the code of the 2 branches
More about it:
https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Comment: Mine is Case 2. After doing this, will the modifications on my feature-branch removed?